# Dropdownlist with Image beside each item

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-membership, asp.net-2.0

How can I have a small image beside each item of asp.net dropdown list.

Regards
ravi

Answer (score 1):

Try this here, great combo box for ASP.

[Obout.com](http://www.obout.com/combobox/index.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to implement your own control, because as far as I know, standard DropDownList uses browser's standard combobox and it does not support images.

You might start with http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx
and modify it to show images

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing in an HTML `select` element. You would have to write it using JavaScript, e.g. something [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1061726/1525767.aspx).